# How to prove that $\sin^2{x} \leq 2|x| $ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ using derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm supposed to define a function, $f(x) = \sin^2{x} - 2|x|$ and take the $1^{st}$ derivative to find the sign of $f'(x)$. Since $|x|$ is not diff at $0$, I'm stuck and have no idea how to approach it after taking the derivative. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: It suffices to show the inequality for $x>0$.

Comment: @MartinR can you elaborate please?

Comment: $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Comment: If you can show that $\sin^2 x \leq 2|x|$ when $x>0$, then you can use that to show $\sin^2x \leq 2|x| =-2x$ when $x<0$. Combine with $f(0) = 0$, and you have that $\sin^2 x \leq 2|x|$ for all real $x$.

Comment: @aschepler $f'(x)=sin {2x} -2 $ for $x>0$. Clearly, $f'(x)<0$ and $f(x)$ is decreasing. Thus, $f(x) < f(0) =0 \rightarrow sin^2 x -2|x|<0$ am i correct?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the idea

Comment: @Lucifer: Hi. I posted an answer. If you are not familiar with the mean value theorem, or there is something else in my answer which you find confusing, please let me know.

Comment: @Joe Thank you so much. I got it

Comment: A similar proof could use that $f(x) -f(0)= \int_0^x f'(t) dt$ when $x>0$. (And it doesn't matter that $f'(0)$ is not defined to find the integral value.)

Comment: @Joe The question's author always gets a notification when an answer is posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to show that $f(x)\le 0$ for all $x$. As Martin R mentions in the comments, the statement is true for $x=0$, and since $f(-x)=f(x)$, it suffices to prove the statement is true for $x>0$. So consider any $x_0>0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,x_0]$ and differentiable on $(0,x_0)$, the mean value theorem ensures that there is an $\alpha\in(0,x_0)$ such that
$$
f(x_0)=f(0)+f'(\alpha)x_0
$$
On the interval $(0,\infty)$, we have $f'(x)=2\sin x\cos x-2=\sin(2x)-2$, and so $f'(\alpha)$ is negative. Thus, $f(x_0)=f(0)+f'(\alpha)x_0<f(0)=0$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Lucifer: No problem! As an "extension question", you might want to try using the mean value theorem to prove that if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is positive on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.